# Metodos update() y destroy() no funcionan en Laravel API RestFul

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo una API RestFul con Laravel, y todo va bien con los metodos, excepto el metodo `update()` y el metodo `destroy()`, (`PUT` y `DELETE` respectivamente), no es problema de `CORS`, si entra en la funcion ya que comprobe que al usar los respectivos vervbos `HTTP` entra en la funcion correspondiente, solo que no esta ejecutando lo que se hace dentro de ella

Dejo el codigo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Client;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;



class ClientController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        return Client::paginate(5);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return Client::create(Input::all());
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        return Client::findOrFail($id);
    }


    public function update($id)
    {
        Client::findOrFail($id)->update(Input::all()); 

        return Client::findOrFail($id);
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $deleted = Client::findOrFail($id);
        Client::findOrFail($id)->delete();

        return $deleted;
    } 
}
```

y aca el codigo de mi `route.php`

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');
```

Comment: No muestra ningún error ? . está seguro que ingresan en los métodos respectivos ? . si hace un `dd($id)` en cada método, ¿funciona ?

Comment: Si, entran en el respectivo método, hice un printb de la id y la imprime correctamente solo que no me guarda los cambios, y si no muestra ningún error, solo me retorna el registro pero sin ningún cambio :(

Comment: Muestranos como tienes el modelo `Client`

Answer (score 0):

No uses findOrFail() creo que ahi tenes el problema.
Fijate de probar esto

```
public function update(Client $client)
{
    $client->update(Input::all()); // Yo uso el Request $request no el Input pero no debería ser el problema
    return $client;
}

public function destroy(Client $client)
{
    $client->delete();
    return $deleted;
}
```

Sino probá optimizando tu código, en cada metodo estas haciendo 2 llamadas a la base de datos

```
public function update($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    $client->update(Input::all()); 

    return $client;
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    $client->delete();

    return $client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ver qué pasa, En routes/api.php añadí este listener para que te imprima en storage/logs/laravel.log las instrucciones SQL

```
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {

    Log::debug($query->sql);
    Log::debug($query->bindings);
    Log::debug($query->time);

});
```

En el modelo:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];
```

Update:

```
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    $client->fill($request->all());
    $client->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $cliente= Client::findOrFail( $id );
    if ( $cliente->update( $request->all() ) ){
       //lo que desees hacer despues de actualizar
    }else{
      return redirect()->back(); 
    }

public function destroy($id)
{
    $cliente = Client::findOrFail($id);
    if($cliente->delete()){
       //mensaje de eliminado con exito
     }else{
       //mensaje de error al eliminar.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

El metodo `delete()`, solo devuelve true o false,lo mejor es colocarlo en un tryCatch, recomiendo usar `$request->validated()` en vez de `$request->all()`, tambien crear un ClientRequest para las validaciones.

```
public function update(ClientRequest $request, Client $client)
{
    try {
        $client->update($request->validated());
        return new ClientResource($client);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function destroy(Client $client)
{
    try {
        $client->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'delete success'
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿por qué no intentás con un try catch y capturando la excepción de ModelNotfound? En caso que falle, te debería arrojar algún error ahí.

```
try {
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
}catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        //codigo a ejecutar si falla
}
```

Otra manera sería guardar tu client en una variable y después verificar su contenido.

```
$client = Client::findOrFail($id);
var_dump($client);
```